# Dynamic number of elements with dynamic width untill two rows are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I am displaying multiple div elements next to each other on the bottom of page.

The number of these elements and their width is unknown - meaning I don't know them in advance, as they are loaded dynamically depending on some other rules.

What I want to achieve, is to display only two rows of these elements, and once another element would break on third line, just show some indicator that there are more elements that can be expanded.

I do not want to have any scroll bars there.

[image]

I am using jquery and knockout.js.

Elements should be reorganized when screen size changes.

JS

```
// all the elements representing the divs
self.tags = ko.observableArray();
// disaplayed elements
self.tagsPreview = ko.observableArray()
```

HTML

```
<div id="tagsContainer">
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: tagsPreview, as: 'tag' } -->
        <div data-bind="text: tag.title" class="tag"></div>            
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tagsContainer .tag {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;     
    height: 30px;    
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 5px;        
}
```

I don't know how to calculate or find out the elements that should be assigned to the `tagsPreview` observable. Any suggestions? I don't think this can be done via css only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get halfway there just by using a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for layout.

Displaying the overflow indicator is a matter of counting how many rows there are, which is to say how many distinct values for top there are among the items.

In addition to using `setMoreTags` in the `afterRender`, you would also want to set it up to run any time the container was resized.

```js
const names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five golden rings', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten',
  'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen'
];
const vm = {
  // all the elements representing the divs
  tags: ko.observableArray([]),
  moreTags: ko.observable(false),
  setMoreTags: function () {
    // Count how many different tops there are among the tags
    // If more than two, moreTags is true
    const tags = document.querySelectorAll('#tagsContainer .tag');
    const tops = {};
    
    for (const t of tags) {
      tops[t.getBoundingClientRect().top] = true;
    }
    vm.moreTags(Object.keys(tops).length > 2);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

const i = setInterval(() => {
  if (names.length) {
    vm.tags.push({
      title: names.shift()
    });
  } else {
    clearInterval(i);
  }
}, 500);
```

```css
#tagsContainer {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-height: 68px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

#tagsContainer .tag {
  border: thin solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#tagsContainer .more-indicator {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="tagsContainer">
  <!-- ko foreach: { data: tags, as: 'tag', afterRender: setMoreTags } -->
  <div data-bind="text: tag.title" class="tag"></div>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if: moreTags -->
  <div class="more-indicator">...</div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome solution. It took me a while to get it why it works, especially i had to learn about the flexbox layout, but i like it!